# Why does numpy.polyfit return non-zero values for straight line data?

Tags: python, numpy

Math gurus please help!

I'm using numpy.polyfit to get the "slope" of a line from a python list. I need to act on the data if it's a negative slope, but I'm getting very slightly negative/positive values instead of a zero (horizontal) slope, and am unsure why.

eg. [206, 206, 206, 206, 206, 206, 206, 206] gives -1.92165829214e-14 rather than 0

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def lineOfBestFit(data):

    y = data
    x = range(len(y))

    coefficients = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    return coefficients[0]
```

Comment: In general you should expect fits to only be accurate up to some small precision. That slope is ~ -2*10^-14, which is supremely small.

Comment: I've been rounding to 10 decimal places to get around it. It works, but I was wondering if there was a better way of using polyfit, or if I was using it incorrectly.

Comment: Keep in mind that machine precision for a 32-bit double is ~ 10^-16, which will be an absolute limiting factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.polyfit` uses [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) to estimate the coefficients appearing in your fit. Without going into too much detail, this involves estimating the inverse of a matrix, which can be hard when singular values appear. Anytime you expect a parameter to be close to 0, your result when inverting is only good up to some precision, so you should expect a small non-zero result.

Try turning on `full=True` when calling `numpy.polyfit` to get more diagnostics from the fit, such as the errors on the fit parameters.

Comment: Cheers, Doc. I will just work with the non-zero values.